# How to do the domain acts like another domain?

Tags: server, dns, cross-domain

I want to do that:

http://foo.example.com  ->  http://customdomain.com

http://bar.example.com  ->  http://anotherdomain.com

...

It's like Tumblr or Blogger custom domain using. My user's can create a website, these sites serve in my subdomains. However, if user wants to set custom domain for your site, then http://userscustomdomain.com actually will open http://foo.example.com but everyone can see the domain of http://userscustomdomain.com

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your users should make Cname records that point to your domain, for example
www.usercustomdomain.com CNAME foo.example.com.

When that is set up, you need to make your application listen to the customers hostname.

Cheers!

Comment: Should cname records be on same IP address?